# Ajax form submission does not occur on .prepend() for textbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I add `<input type="text">` via `$('#').click(function(){});`  Then use form.js to write into the table, but does not.

If the text is standalone it does write.

below is the code used to ajax form.js.

```
$(function() {   
  $("#c .button").click(function() {     

    var text = $("#N").val();     
    var dataString = 'N='+ N;      
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",     
      url: "s.php",     
      data: dataString,     
      success: function(){       
        $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
      }
    });      
    return false;   }); 
});
```

Should I use .live or .on.  Neither of which works though. Any ideas as to why it does not work.

[update]

```
<input type="text" name="N" id="N"><input type="button" value="Ok" id="c" class="button">
```

Comment: the var "N" don't exists, and the correct format of data is {name:value}

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya "N" is the id value of the textbox.

Comment: @jean , how can you use that as a variable ???????

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya Q updated with html code.  variable?

Comment: var dataString = 'N='+ N; so what is this 2 nd N

Comment: The value taken from name="N" from the input textbox

Answer (score 0):

```
change data: dataString,
```

to

```
data: dataString:dataString,
```

and in

```
var dataString = 'N='+ N;
```

what is this variable `N`

also you should use

```
  $("#c , .button").click(function()
```

instead of

```
  $("#c .button").click(function()
```